# Opensource JavaDoc editor

Tags: open-source, javadoc

I have spent the days looking for an Opensource JavaDoc editor or a way to edit JavaDocs easily or creating package-info files and come back empty.

I am basically after a way to change the way the packages are listed. The automation framework I work on is undergoing some potential future changes. These changes in a nutshell will organise our test scripts in a way where they are split up into business areas and then into smaller packages of business functions within that area.

We use IntelliJ and the default JavaDoc generator creates the JavaDocs in a way where it makes a list of all the packages, what I want to do is have it create a list of the main packages (business areas) and then the sub packages within that contain our test scripts (business functions).

For example:

BusinessAreaOne contain BusinessFunctionOne, BusinessFunctionTwo and BusinessFunctionThree.
BusinessAreaTwo Contains BusinessFunctionFour and BusinessFunctionFive.
The BusinessFunction packages in turn contain scripts that cover just that business function.

I haven't been able to find an editor that does what I would like and I don't think editing the files manually is practical each time there is an update.

If there is no opensource java editor can do this are there any suggestions of a work around?

As I mentioned I have tried creating package-info files but as far as I can tell you can only add a description to that package. Is there any tutorials out there or does anybody know a way I can get it to display the list of packages within the selected package?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadoc doesn't treat package hierarchies as nested hierarchies, it just flattens them all into a list, as you probably noticed, so your business functions will just appear as entries in the list between the business areas.

Looking for a Javadoc editor is not going to help you because the Javadocs you end up with is the output from the Javadoc compilation process, and there's no specific tag you can put in your code that will influence the compilation process in the way you're looking for.

You would have to write something to override Javadoc's implementation of its HTML formatter specifically for the package list using:

> Javadoc Doclets
>   You can customize the content and format of the Javadoc tool's output by using doclets. The Javadoc tool has a default "built-in" doclet, called the standard doclet, that generates HTML-formatted API documentation. You can modify or subclass the standard doclet, or write your own doclet to generate HTML, XML, MIF, RTF or whatever output format you'd like. Information about doclets and their use is at the following locations:
>
> [Javadoc Doclets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/index.html)

You would use your own implementation of the `Standard` Doclet, finding the right class to override - try looking first at the `PackageDoc` class. I'm going through this learning process myself at the moment, but here's [the info on Doclet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/standard-doclet.html) and there's a link at the bottom of that page to the source code which will illustrate how to do it.

Of course there could be an easier way of doing it and if I discover it I'll come back to update this answer.